# giving access token to file in cloud storage using PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I can now upload my image to google cloud storage using PHP but face some problem. When I access the image from firebase console show like this.

[image: image uploded from PHP]

but when I upload it manually it show like this

[image: image uploaded manually]

and here is my code for upload from PHP

[image: code for upload]

the difference between PHP upload and manually upload is the access token, from PHP where can I pass the access token?

Comment: The duplicate describes how to add a token to the metadata of the object.  You will have to figure out the syntax for PHP.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for the reference, it works now

Comment: in PHP you need to generate the policy first here is the code example to generate policy